# Equivalent to "Deutschamerikaner" for Americans living in Germany?

Tags: single-word-request

[Wikipedia states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_American):

> German Americans (German: *Deutschamerikaner*) are citizens of the
>   United States who were either born in Germany or are of German
>   ancestry.

Is there an equivalent German word for German citizens born in the US? *Amerikanerdeutsche* doesn't sound correct to me.

Comment: I would use the same word (and write it with a hyphen). Note that the context of the Wikipedia article is the US.

Comment: _Amerikanerdeutsche_ is completely uncommon. Wouldn't work at all because as user unknown noted in German Amerika does not denote a single country.

Comment: I don't think, that many German people do make a real difference between the too situations. What about the people who live some time here, some time there. My opinion: It depends on the context, if you are talking of US or Germany. OTOH, the last part may stress a little bit more the country of main residence. And because there are living more Germans in the US than in US-citzens in Germany, we are more used the first term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

US-Deutsche würde funktionieren. Amerika ist größer als die USA. :)

Comment: _US-Deutsche_ klingt meinem Sprachempfinden nach auch besser als _Amerika(ner)deutsche_.

Comment: What about a German living in the US without citizenship. Could he be called US-Deutscher too ("Ein Deutscher, der in den USA lebt.") ? Maybe. But I would not call him Deutschamerikaner.

Comment: @Philm: Wenn aus dem Kontext klar wird, ob ein Deutscher in den USA oder ein US-Amerikaner in Deutschland gemeint ist, geht wohl beides. Wenn nicht, dann beides nicht.